# Adding natural dragging effect to ImageView same as Facebook Messanger chat heads using Rebound library

Tags: android, facebook, spring, animation

I am developing one app where I am dragging around my ImageView in Activity.
I have configured [**Facebook Rebound library**](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/) for spring animation which is originally used in Facebook Messenger's chat heads animations. I want to add this kind of animations to my ImageView when I drag it.
  [**VIDEO**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECLkrDfDAG4)

So far I am able to get spring animation when I touch ImageView (implemented spring on rootview), this is my code. How can I implement that natural type of dragging effect to my ImageView.

```
public class MainTry extends Activity {

    int windowwidth;
    int windowheight;

    private LayoutParams layoutParams;
    private final BaseSpringSystem mSpringSystem = SpringSystem.create();
    private FrameLayout mRootView;
    private Spring spring;
    private View mImageView;
    private VelocityTracker velocity = null;
    private float dx;
    private float dy;
    private View rootView;
    private ImageView img;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    // Create a system to run the physics loop for a set of springs.
    SpringSystem springSystem = SpringSystem.create();

    // Add a spring to the system.
    spring = springSystem.createSpring();

    rootView = getWindow().getDecorView()
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // spring.setEndValue(1);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // spring.setEndValue(0);
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Add a listener to observe the motion of the spring.
    spring.addListener(new SimpleSpringListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
            // You can observe the updates in the spring
            // state by asking its current value in onSpringUpdate.
            float value = (float) spring.getCurrentValue();
            float scale = .5f - (value * 0.1f);
            img.setScaleX(scale);
            img.setScaleY(scale);
        }
    });
    // spring.setEndValue(1);

    img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img
                    .getLayoutParams();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                dx = event.getRawX() - 10;
                dy = event.getRawY() - 10;

                if (velocity == null) {
                    // Retrieve a new VelocityTracker object to watch the
                    // velocity of a motion.
                    velocity = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                } else {
                    // Reset the velocity tracker back to its initial state.
                    velocity.clear();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                dx = event.getRawX() - 10;
                dy = event.getRawY() - 10;


                velocity.addMovement(event);
                spring.setVelocity(velocity.getYVelocity());
                spring.setCurrentValue(dy);
                spring.setEndValue(dy);


                layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) dx - 10;
                layoutParams.topMargin = (int) dy - 10;
                img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                velocity.addMovement(event);
                spring.setVelocity(velocity.getYVelocity());
                spring.setCurrentValue(event.getRawY() - 10);
                spring.setEndValue(0);

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about this:

```
class V extends View implements SpringListener {
    private static final int NUM_ELEMS = 4;
    private Spring[] mXSprings = new Spring[NUM_ELEMS];
    private Spring[] mYSprings = new Spring[NUM_ELEMS];
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        SpringSystem ss = SpringSystem.create();

        Spring s;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMS; i++) {
            s = ss.createSpring();
            s.setSpringConfig(new MySpringConfig(200, i == 0? 8 : 15 + i * 2, i, true));
            s.addListener(this);
            mXSprings[i] = s;

            s = ss.createSpring();
            s.setSpringConfig(new MySpringConfig(200, i == 0? 8 : 15 + i * 2, i, false));
            s.addListener(this);
            mYSprings[i] = s;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mXSprings[0].setCurrentValue(w / 2);
        mYSprings[0].setCurrentValue(0);

        mXSprings[0].setEndValue(w / 2);
        mYSprings[0].setEndValue(h / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpringActivate(Spring s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpringAtRest(Spring s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpringEndStateChange(Spring s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpringUpdate(Spring s) {
        MySpringConfig cfg = (MySpringConfig) s.getSpringConfig();
        if (cfg.index < NUM_ELEMS - 1) {
            Spring[] springs = cfg.horizontal? mXSprings : mYSprings;
            springs[cfg.index + 1].setEndValue(s.getCurrentValue());
        }
        if (cfg.index == 0) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mXSprings[0].setEndValue(event.getX());
        mYSprings[0].setEndValue(event.getY());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int i = NUM_ELEMS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(i == 0? 255 : 192 - i * 128 / NUM_ELEMS);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 
                    (float) mXSprings[i].getCurrentValue() - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                    (float) mYSprings[i].getCurrentValue() - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                    mPaint);
        }
    }

    class MySpringConfig extends SpringConfig {
        int index;
        boolean horizontal;
        public MySpringConfig(double tension, double friction, int index, boolean horizontal) {
            super(tension, friction);
            this.index = index;
            this.horizontal = horizontal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi pskink, once I have created the class (your code above) how exactly do I use it? Can you please share how exactly can we put your class to use? thanks

Comment: I tried that all I see is the image. http://imgur.com/N43ZApo
It does not drag. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Supreet did you run that code on the emulator/device?

Comment: Hi @pskink I can not run your code in an emulator or device because we don't use java for Android Development. We use Xamarin.android & I ported your code (exactly as it is, line by line) in C#. The Image I shared is in an Emulator from the ported code.

Comment: I got it. The only thing we did not implement was Invalidate on SpringUpdate when index was 0. That was the trick. Thank you for such an awesome code.

Comment: @Supreet so I'm afraid your port was not perfect,  try my original java code,  i hope you have eclipse/android studio on your hands to compile and run it

Comment: yes works like a charm. Sharing the Dot Net port source code on Git. It should benefit people using Xamarin.Android

Comment: @Supreet great,  nice to hear it, note that you can simplify it by making only one element (NUM_ELEMS == 1) but the effect will be less natural

Comment: Yes I tried that. Here is my version for folks wanting to work with Rebound in Dot Net world. Works with Xamarin.Android too. It also has a post of your sample above. https://github.com/supreettare/ReboundDotNet/tree/master/ReboundTest

Comment: I down voted this, because there seems to have zero explanation of the code which is added to this answer. Request you to add it, so that I can upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: @bundleofjoy what can i say? you have **complete** working class, not a pseudocode, not a snippet of a code that needs to be integrated with the other code to be working, you have out of the box class to be used and still it's too less for you, other guys were happy but not you, i can only say: i'm sorry...

Comment: IMHO This code would be more useful if you explained what it was doing. Small snippet, out of box product, it mostly doesnt matter at SO as long as it is relevant and completely answers the question. What if, in future, this "out of the box" class doesnt cater to an edge case, and the clueless person who plugged this into his code is still clueless about it? Anyway I didnt mean to offend you. Thanks though!

Comment: @bundleofjoy so should i explain what onTouchEvent is, what onDraw is etc? take the code, add some Log.d statements and see how it works. and if still in doubts ask here instead of dovnwoting, i am not going to do anyone's homework...

Comment: Not at all @pskink. I dont mean the syntactical explanation. Theres the android dev site for that. I meant stuff like the general flow of how it works.. Lots of Math in this code, such as this `i == 0? 8 : 15 + i * 2, i, true`, for example. Generally, people dont require spoon-feeding, just a gentle nudge in the right direction. A one-liner would've been sufficient, though! Thanks again! Again, apologies if I offended you!

Comment: @bundleofjoy i wrote in one of my comment "note that you can simplify it by making only one element (NUM_ELEMS == 1) but the effect will be less natural" so do it and everything will be clear... the effect will not be so smooth but you will know how stuff works

Comment: Thanks @pskink. Would you mind adding (editing ) that in the answer? Upvote/downvote is locked because its been more than 30 mins since I downvoted. Also, it would help the innocent amateur who chances upon this answer! TIA!

Comment: @bundleofjoy ok so i did someone's homework: http://pastebin.com/wzyMx9bX this is a simplified example

Comment: @pskink I think you misunderstood. I really didnt need this :) 

This fact which you just told me - "note that you can simplify it by making only one element `(NUM_ELEMS == 1)` but the effect will be less natural"

Please add this point in the answer is what I meant! :D

Comment: @bundleofjoy you didnt need this? so why or earth you downvoted my answer at all? just for fun or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72476/discussion-between-bundleofjoy-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2):

i have used above V class directly in Window-manager and it's work perfectly and  chatHead move like facebook messenger.

```
public class ChatHeadService extends Service
{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private WindowManager windowManager;

    private Point szWindow = new Point();


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v(Utils.LogTag, "Start Service");
    }

    private
    void handleStart(){

         windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (Build . VERSION . SDK_INT >= Build . VERSION_CODES . HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager . getDefaultDisplay() . getSize(szWindow);
        } else {
            int w = windowManager . getDefaultDisplay() . getWidth();
            int h = windowManager . getDefaultDisplay() . getHeight();
            szWindow . set(w, h);
        }

        WindowManager . LayoutParams params = new WindowManager . LayoutParams(
            WindowManager . LayoutParams . WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager . LayoutParams . WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager . LayoutParams . TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
            WindowManager . LayoutParams . FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            PixelFormat . TRANSLUCENT
        );

        params . gravity = Gravity . TOP | Gravity . LEFT;
        params . x       = 50;
        params . y       = 100;

        V vImg = new V(this);

        windowManager . addView(vImg, params);


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (startId == Service . START_STICKY) {
                handleStart();
            }
        }

        return super . onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
                super . onDestroy();
        if (windowManager != null) {
            // windowManager.removeView(chatHeadView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works great! one thing is that when you touch the screen, say for opening a new app/swiping on home page, the floating icon reaches where you touched, blocking other events. How could that be prevented? means only when you touch the icon itself the event triggeres

Comment: how can i remove chat head by dragging bottom of screen like Facebook messenger chat head ?