# How to create rebound popup in android similar to Paper App (IOS)?

Tags: android, popup, bounce

I am trying to create rebound popup similar to paper app(IOS), I tried alot to create the same popup but failed. I found a link https://github.com/facebook/rebound where facebook has released is rebound popup library but I am facing difficulties to create the same popup.Below is the youtube video where you can find the popup on 35-40 seconds also I am attaching a screenshot for the same. Please do let me know your suggestion as I have stuck here and can't proceed my app without this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A7U8R1Ql_Q&feature=youtu.be

[image]

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976343/adding-natural-dragging-effect-to-imageview-same-as-facebook-massanger-chat-head on how you can use rebound

Comment: Thanks for your support. The class you posted seems to be very useful but I am unable to use it on popup. can you please tell me that how can I use this class in activity to rebound popup?

Comment: this a simple example how you can use rebound with multiple Springs,  the most important is Spring.setEndValue() and do something with the value in the listener