# Using Rebound API with ImageView

Tags: android, facebook, spring, animation

I am currently in need of making ChatHeads like Facebook. Following the tutorials I found, I can make a ChatHead start from Service. However, when I added Rebound API from Facebook to make it smooth, I created a customized view like this post: [Adding natural dragging effect to ImageView same as Facebook Messanger chat heads using Rebound library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976343/adding-natural-dragging-effect-to-imageview-same-as-facebook-massanger-chat-head) ;
but it seems to block every background touch. I can only drag the ChatHead around without able to touch anything else. How can I make a ChatHead that is still smooth draggable and also can interact with the background also (just the same as Facebook)? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advanced

BTW, this is my view

```
class ChatHeadView extends View implements SpringListener, SpringSystemListener {

private Spring xSpring;
private Spring ySpring;
private SpringSystem springSystem;
private final SpringConfig COASTING;
private float x;
private float y;
private boolean dragging;
private float radius = 100;
private float downX;
private float downY;
private float lastX;
private float lastY;
private VelocityTracker velocityTracker;
private float centerX;
private float centerY;
int screenWidth, screenHeight;

private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
private Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.ic_launcher);

public ChatHeadView(Context context, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    springSystem = SpringSystem.create();
    springSystem.addListener(this);

    COASTING = SpringConfig.fromOrigamiTensionAndFriction(0, 0.5);
    COASTING.tension = 0;

    xSpring = springSystem.createSpring();
    ySpring = springSystem.createSpring();
    xSpring.addListener(this);
    ySpring.addListener(this);

    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    centerX = getWidth() / 2f;
                    centerY = getHeight() / 2f;

                    xSpring.setCurrentValue(centerX).setAtRest();
                    ySpring.setCurrentValue(centerY).setAtRest();
                    getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                }
            });

    screenWidth = width;
    screenHeight = height;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, x - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2,
            y - mBitmap.getHeight(), mPaint);
}

@SuppressLint("Recycle")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getRawX();
    float touchY = event.getRawY();
    boolean ret = false;

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        downX = touchX;
        downY = touchY;
        lastX = downX;
        lastY = downY;
        velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
        velocityTracker.addMovement(event);
        if (downX > x - radius && downX < x + radius && downY > y - radius
                && downY < y + radius) {
            dragging = true;
            ret = true;
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (!dragging) {
            break;
        }
        velocityTracker.addMovement(event);
        float offsetX = lastX - touchX;
        float offsetY = lastY - touchY;
        xSpring.setCurrentValue(xSpring.getCurrentValue() - offsetX)
                .setAtRest();
        ySpring.setCurrentValue(ySpring.getCurrentValue() - offsetY)
                .setAtRest();
        checkConstraints();
        ret = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        if (!dragging) {
            break;
        }
        velocityTracker.addMovement(event);
        velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
        dragging = false;
        ySpring.setSpringConfig(COASTING);
        xSpring.setSpringConfig(COASTING);
        downX = 0;
        downY = 0;
        xSpring.setVelocity(velocityTracker.getXVelocity());
        ySpring.setVelocity(velocityTracker.getYVelocity());
        ret = true;
    }

    lastX = touchX;
    lastY = touchY;
    return ret;
}

@Override
public void onSpringUpdate(Spring s) {
    x = (float) xSpring.getCurrentValue();
    y = (float) ySpring.getCurrentValue();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void onSpringActivate(Spring s) {
}

@Override
public void onSpringAtRest(Spring s) {
}

@Override
public void onSpringEndStateChange(Spring s) {
}

@Override
public void onBeforeIntegrate(BaseSpringSystem springSystem) {

}

@Override
public void onAfterIntegrate(BaseSpringSystem springSystem) {
    checkConstraints();
}

private void checkConstraints() {
    if (x + radius >= screenWidth) {
        xSpring.setVelocity(-xSpring.getVelocity());
        xSpring.setCurrentValue(xSpring.getCurrentValue()
                - (x + radius - screenWidth), false);
    }
    if (x - radius <= 0) {
        xSpring.setVelocity(-xSpring.getVelocity());
        xSpring.setCurrentValue(xSpring.getCurrentValue() - (x - radius),
                false);
    }
    if (y + radius >= screenHeight) {
        ySpring.setVelocity(-ySpring.getVelocity());
        ySpring.setCurrentValue(ySpring.getCurrentValue()
                - (y + radius - screenHeight), false);
    }
    if (y - radius <= 0) {
        ySpring.setVelocity(-ySpring.getVelocity());
        ySpring.setCurrentValue(ySpring.getCurrentValue() - (y - radius),
                false);
    }

}

}
```

this is where I add View with WindowManager:

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
screenWidth = size.x;
screenHeight = size.y;
chatHeadView = new ChatHeadView(this, screenWidth, screenHeight);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

windowManager.addView(chatHeadView, params);
```

Comment: I already used windowmanager to add this view, if I add just an ImageView it won't block the background touch but when I add the view I get from your answer, it blocks everything but the view.

Comment: I mean I am already able to add an icon and smoothly drag it, but when the icon appear (started from service), I can't either click or touch anything on the background anymore.

Comment: my answer was how to use rebound library,  not how to make chatheads

Comment: yeah I know that, at first I just used an ImageView to make chatheads, it didn't look nice. Then I come accross your answer and I wanted to replace the windowmanager.addView(imageView,params) with windowmanager.add(customView,params) so the chatheads can be rebound. I successfully added the customView you gave in the answer; however there's something prevent me from clicking outside. Can you please let me know where I'm wrong?

Comment: what is the size of the view you are adding via addView method?

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! It turns out the view I added covers the whole screen because I wanted to be able to drag the chathead everywhere. How stupid I am...btw, what should I do in order to be able to drag as now but not create "a mask" that covers everything? Sorry for causing you too much trouble.

Comment: as for now, in order to be able to drag the chathead around the screen, I add a whole screen view using WindowManager. Because it is whole screen, I couldn't click on anything on the background. So what should I do so that I'm able to interact with the background while the chathead is still draggable across the whole screen?

Comment: just drag it if getX()/getY() is within your view bounds,  otherwise skip the MotionEvent

Comment: but my view (added by WindowManager) covers up the whole screen so I cannot click on the item in background (behind the view)

Comment: So make it wrap_content, wrap_content

Comment: I updated my question, I set it to wrap_content, wrap_content but it's still covers the whole screen. And if I make it smaller, than I can't drag the chathead freely everywhere on screen anymore (I can only drag it inside the view bounds)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)

> Window flag: even when this window is focusable (its FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE is not set), allow any pointer events outside of the window to be sent to the windows behind it. Otherwise it will consume all pointer events itself, regardless of whether they are inside of the window.

It's saying about your problem.

Instead, try  **WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE** flag.
you can get TouchEvent on the view and it won't consume other events.