# Move bitmap along a changing path

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

this might not even be possible with Bitmaps but I have a bitmap that moves left and right on the screen, lets call it bitmap1. My goal is to have another bitmap, lets call it bitmap2, to move a long a path towards the original bitmap. Now the issue here is that bitmap1 is constantly changing, so how could I create a changing path that moves bitmap2 towards bitmap1 smoothly? Thanks

Comment: Do you guys think AndEngine would make this easier?

Comment: what bout Rebound? http://facebook.github.io/rebound/

Comment: I am not sure if this would help me, or maybe I just can't see it. Could you explain how it would work?

Comment: "Rebound is a java library that models spring dynamics" imagine one end of the spring is attached to bitmap1 which moves, the other end of the spring is attached to bitmap2 which will be moving in sync with bitmap1 but with a nice effect that the spring provides

Comment: see my sample view here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23977598/2252830 and its simplified version: http://pastebin.com/wzyMx9bX

Comment: This is def what I am looking for. I saw your simple example and tried it out but the bitmap is not being drawn to the canvas?

Comment: In my example i draw one bitmao following the finger,  yiu need to draw two bitmaps: one that moves as you want and the second following the first one

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks, I'll get back to you with how it went

Comment: i know in the onSizeChanged method I need to set the spring current value to my bitmaps x,y coordinates but I am having trouble with it

Comment: Disregard that, I got it to work. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: You owe me a beer then ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing a similar problem to mine then check out [Rebound](http://facebook.github.io/rebound), courtesy of pskink. It solved my issues.